# Calling AMFPHP from Red 5 returns a long double

Tags: flash, red5, amfphp

I'm running the latest build (I'm pretty sure it's 1.0) on Ubuntu and I am calling a function on an amfphp service on another server.  Everything seems to be in order, but I am getting a strange return value using the following code:

```
String url = "http://path.to.our.server/gateway.php"; 
RemotingClient client = new RemotingClient(url); 
Object[] args = new Object[]{"Hello world!"}; 
Object result =client.invokeMethod("service.manager.say", args); 
if(debug) System.out.println("return from server: "+result.toString());
```

All the say() function does is return the phrase "hello from the server" as a string.

```
function say($what){
  return "hello from the server";
}
```

What I'm getting, however, is the following result:

> return from server:
>   1.6846524729092E-310

Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Update with the answer.  Red5 doesn't work correctly with AMFPHP 1.9.  Switching to AMFPHP 1.2 solved the issue. Also, switching to Zend AMF worked as expected.